# Zip certain files having filenames alphanumerically bigger than others

Tags: command-line, bash, filename, gzip

I gzipped files in a slurm job. But job canceled before it is done. It takes so long(~10min for a file, and there is 200 files). How can I zip only the remaining files which are not zipped yet?

```
$ ls
 
SRR7121484_1.fastq
SRR7121484_1.fastq.gz
SRR7121484_2.fastq
SRR7121484_2.fastq.gz
SRR7121485_1.fastq
SRR7121485_2.fastq
SRR7121488_1.fastq
SRR7121488_2.fastq
....
```

As you see, all the remaining files are bigger than the number **7121485**. I tried to extract this value and use conditionals, however no success yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just run `gzip` on all the `fastq` files directly. By default, it will ask if you want to overwrite the existing files:

```
$ gzip -k *.fastq
SRR7121484_1.fastq.gz already exists -- do you wish to overwrite (y or n)?
```

If `gzip` can't read anything from standard input, it simply skips these files:

```
% gzip -k *.fastq -v < /dev/null
gzip: SRR7121484_1.fastq.gz already exists -- skipping
gzip: SRR7121484_2.fastq.gz already exists -- skipping
SRR7121485_1.fastq:   -99.9% -- replaced with SRR7121485_1.fastq.gz
SRR7121485_2.fastq:   -99.9% -- replaced with SRR7121485_2.fastq.gz
SRR7121488_1.fastq:   -99.9% -- replaced with SRR7121488_1.fastq.gz
SRR7121488_2.fastq:   -99.9% -- replaced with SRR7121488_2.fastq.gz
```

So, just run:

```
gzip -k *.fastq < /dev/null
```